# How tall is Foaly?

Tags: artemis-fowl

Foaly is a centaur, and centaurs are usually pretty tall (maybe around 2.5 meters). However, Foaly lives and works with elves, who are around 1 meter tall. Scale everything up and that'd be like humans working with someone who's 4.5 meters tall (or around 15 feet). That doesn't really make sense to me, and doesn't seem to be supported by what I remember from the books, but it also doesn't make much sense that centuars in the *Artemis Fowl* world would be elf-sized.

So, is there any canon indication of how tall centaurs (specifically Foaly) are (is)?

Comment: I think centaurs could be elf-sized. As I recall, even adult demons, which are tall for faeries, are not as tall as an adult human.

Comment: They are definitely small as Foaly is behind Artemis, Butler and, I think, Holy in the size order in Atlantis Complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find an exact answer but he is definitely smaller than human sized. In *Atlantis Complex* Artemis's Atlantis Complex causes him to demand his five allies sit in height order which is pretty useful for this question.

The exact quote is below from the Atlantis Complex Chapter 9: Forbidden Love(emphasis mine):

> Foaly and Mulch arguing for a moment over who was smaller. There was no argument over who was the tallest. Butler sat hunched at the end, chin almost between his knees.Beside him sat Juliet, **then Foaly**, then Mulch, then Holly.

This shows Foaly is roughly Mulch's height. I can't find a quote but Mulch is probably a bit over a metre tall given Holy is 1 metre tall (3' 3") and the fairy average is 1.01m (3' 4"). Given there is no argument between Mulch and Holly, Mulch must be a at least a few centimetres taller with Foaly being at least a centimetre taller again. This gives Foaly a minimum height of around 1.1m (3' 7"). The maximum height is probably 1.7m (5'5") the average height of an Irish woman and we know Foaly is smaller than Juliet.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that Juliet, being a Butler, is taller than the average woman, but other than that this at least confirms that Foaly is elf/miniature horse sized.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Agreed but I can't seem to find a statistic for average height of female bodyguard, wrestler, assassin, servant.

Comment: I'd mostly agree, but this order is when they're sitting here. A centaur sitting down would be taller than he appears